# Traversing "nodes" or multi-level objects with Ebay SDK using davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php

Tags: php, oop, sdk, ebay-api

I'm looking for a solution to use throughout the SDK to return all keys and values from the response object. There must be a way to traverse the response object in Ebay SDK PHP (davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php).

Since each node is an object, I guess this is a 'multidimensional object'??
Even within those, there are arrays. See a small structure below:

I want to print the node/key names to build a "select node/section" tool, then use a loop for the values from the nodes selected. This way I can select any available field in a full response to build my custom reports.

I can handle the UI, but I can't seem to get the object to return keys/values without typing every key name individually.

foreach and implode only got me so far, then I still had to write the names.

(This sample below is only a SMALL fraction of this response nodes; here is the full model: http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetMyeBaySelling.html)

```
  <!-- Call-specific Input Fields -->
  <ActiveList> ItemListCustomizationType
    <Include> boolean </Include>
    <IncludeNotes> boolean </IncludeNotes>
    <ListingType> ListingTypeCodeType </ListingType>
    <Pagination> PaginationType
      <EntriesPerPage> int </EntriesPerPage>
      <PageNumber> int </PageNumber>
    </Pagination>
    <Sort> ItemSortTypeCodeType </Sort>
  </ActiveList>
  <BidList> ItemListCustomizationType
     <Include> boolean </Include>
     <IncludeNotes> boolean </IncludeNotes>
     <Pagination> PaginationType
       <EntriesPerPage> int </EntriesPerPage>
       <PageNumber> int </PageNumber>
     </Pagination>
     <Sort> ItemSortTypeCodeType </Sort>
  </BidList>
  <DeletedFromSoldList> ItemListCustomizationType
    <DurationInDays> int </DurationInDays>
    <Include> boolean </Include>
    <IncludeNotes> boolean </IncludeNotes>
    <Sort> ItemSortTypeCodeType </Sort>
  </DeletedFromSoldList>
  <DeletedFromUnsoldList> ItemListCustomizationType
    <DurationInDays> int </DurationInDays>
    <Include> boolean </Include>
    <IncludeNotes> boolean </IncludeNotes>
    <Sort> ItemSortTypeCodeType </Sort>
  </DeletedFromUnsoldList> ....
```

Comment: Can you clarify that it is the response that you are interested in? The example XML you have used is actually a request.

Comment: Hey David, the XML was just to show the node labels... I want access to every node with your SDK PHP.. My proposed interface will allow me to select any field if I include the node in the request... But there are so many... And it seems that once you get two or three levels into the object, you can only call them by name rather than Loop over them... Forcing me write out every feild name... when I write the function..   the XML for the request that I provided was simply to show how massive the response can be and how time-consuming it would be to write every field to get the value. ...

Comment: I'm looking for a smart solution to Loop through the requests and return field names and values for the possibility to be selected later as part of the UI to customize reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [toArray](http://devbay.net/sdk/guides/guide/request-and-response-objects.html#convert-to-an-array) method that can be called on any of the SDK's objects. The object's property names will become the keys in the associative array that is returned. The value for each key is the value for the object's property. This value can be another associative array if the property's value is another object, or it can be a regular array if the value is an array of values. Using something like array_keys may mean it's possible to iterate the properties of an object. Beware that toArray will only return an array that contains properties that have values. It won't return any properties that are empty.

Other than toArray there is no real way to iterate through the properties of an object as they are implemented using PHP's magic __get and __set methods. There may be ways that use [PHP's refelection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) abilities but this will mean that you code is dependant upon private details of the SDK that can be changed or removed without notice.

Comment: Thanks David, I was able to use the toArray  (  $arrayResponse = $response->OrderArray->toArray();  )  and "print" my node/array key names. ( in the future I could use these to limit which includes to be sent in the request) but for now, as I mentioned, I used these to make my table columns customized based on fields available in the nodes/keys ... I was surprised how deep some of the array levels went. Shipping was 4 or 5 levels deep to get to a value.